# Angular: restricting filter result to current page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

Hi i have implemented uibootstrap pagination in my page. filter is not working perfectly. I want to restrict filter on given page result.

```
     <tr class="customer-row-active" ng-repeat="track in tracks| filter:listFilter| limitTo:itemsPerPage">

                <td>{{track.Id}}</td>
                <td>{{track.Period}}</td>
                <td>{{track.id}}</td>
                <td>{{track.orderId}}</td>

    </tr>

    <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="listFilter">Filter search</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="listFilter" name="listFilter" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid">

                    </div>
```

What am i doing wrong here? Itemsperpage is restrcited to 50. SO i wanted to apply filter only to the current page.It should not include other pages

Comment: what is an error ? Please clearify more

Comment: Did you initialize itemsPerPage? Also what is the error you are getting?